# *_ and *args assigns which value at runtime | python |

Tags: python

Not getting internally what is happening. `*_` amd `*args` doing

what is assigned to `default()` at runtime

**Using `*_` in default**

```
def default(*_):
  return "Not Happy"
a,b=10,20
default(a,b)
```

**Using `*args` in default**

```
def default(*args):
  return "Not Happy"
a,b=10,20
default(a,b)
```

I am trying to understand what is assigned to default at runtime.
if not a and b

I have used website to see visually what happens at runtime during execution but not getting : https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: Why do you think it's not `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo  : can you illustrate

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can define [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (i.e. functions that can take any number of arguments), cf [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) or a [RealPython article](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) about it.

The gist of it is that you can declare a `*whatever` parameter, and Python will collect the variadic parameters and put them in there for you. For example :

```
>>> def foo(*args):
>>>     print(type(args), args)
>>>     
>>> foo()
<class 'tuple'> ()

>>> foo(1)
<class 'tuple'> (1,)

>>> foo(1, 'a')
<class 'tuple'> (1, 'a')

>>> foo(1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
<class 'tuple'> (1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

The convention is to call it `args`, but you can give it another name :

```
>>> def foo(*elephant):
>>>     print(elephant)
>>>     
>>> foo(1, 'a')
(1, 'a')
```

So when you call `default(a,b)`, then `*args` (or `*_` if you want) is filled, and you can use it in your function :

```
>>> def default(*args):
>>>     return "Not Happy" + str(args)
>>> 
>>> a,b=10,20
>>> default(a,b)
'Not Happy(10, 20)'
```

`default` is a function, when you do `default(...)` you **call** that function, meaning you execute the code you wrote in it. You are passing `a` and `b`, none of them is listed as a regular parameter, so both ends up in the `*args` parameter.